# General ODE variation of parameters non-homogenous past exam question

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

If $u_1(x)$ and $u_2(x)$ form a fundamental set of solutions to the corresponding homogeneous version of
$$a(x)y′′(x)+b(x)y′(x)+c(x)y(x) = d(x)$$

use the method of Variation of Parameters to derive an expression for the general solution of the above in terms of $u_1(x)$, $u_2(x)$, their Wronskian, $a(x)$ and $d(x)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look the wroskain and jacobian are required to verify the independence of the solutions, from that just follow the method in your notes.